# Hide advanced tab for certain users under publish option in tridion

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion

We would like to hide the Advanced Tab option for a certain users on the CME as some users misuse the options provided under this tab and the publishing queue gets affected.

Could you please suggest how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most logical way is to use GUI extension where you can disable tab, or certain options on it based on current user permitions.

Comment: user permissions does not work. you must write own logic in GUI extension customization.